# Avoiding loss of significance without series.

Tags: numerical-methods

How could the function $$f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}-1}$$ be computed to avoid loss of significance?

I know that $$f(x)=\frac{\sin x((x^2+1)^{1/2}+1)}{x^2}$$
But $x^2$ has a problem....
How to solve this problem??

Comment: What do you mean by "loss of significance" (maybe "indeterminate form"? That's a wild guess.)? At what point do you want to evaluate the function Again, a guess... $0$?)

Comment: If we compute the function f(x) near 0, then original form f(x)'s error is big. Thus, I want to change f(x)'s form.

Comment: How do you define the error in this case -- are you tying it to a particular representation system (IEEE something)? How do you "compute" the function, for a start? (also, note that $\lvert f(x)\rvert \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} \infty$: you *cannot* get a bounded absolute error in any floating-point representation system, I believe the best you can aim for is a good relative error)

Comment: Yes. The error means relative error.

Comment: What do you mean by "$x^2$ has a problem", then? Is $x$ so small that you're worried about $x^2$ underflowing?

Comment: Right.. I want to miss "denominator is 0" situation.

Comment: Possible idea: you have $f(x) = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{x}{6} + o(x^2)$ around $0$, and computing instead $g(x)=  \frac{2}{x} + \frac{x}{6}$ the ratio $f(x)/g(x)$ is $1 - o(x^3)$ (actually, [even $1+O(x^4)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=series+((sin+x)%2F(sqrt(x%5E2%2B1)-1))%2F(2%2Fx%2B+x%2F6))). Would that be good for you? (But you still have to compute a quantity that blows to $\infty$.... since you want to approximate a function that does.)

Comment: This problem cannot use series ...

Comment: OK, then I give up. (I cannot understand what you can, cannot do, allow, do not allow, and aim at achieving in the end; and I am not even clear on the computation model you want to work in...)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with the original form seems to be the subtractive cancellation in the denominator. This goes away when you rewrite to
$$ f(x) = \frac{(\sin x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}+1)}{x^2} $$
You may still have a problem in the denominator if $x$ can be so small that $x^2$ underflows -- but it would seem that this could be taken care of by
$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}{x} $$

Comment: How to compute right term?

Comment: @asfajaf: You mean the right factor? I don't see there's a problem there. If $x\approx 0$ then the numerator collapses nice and smoothly into $\sqrt{1}+1=2$ -- but that only happens when the _true_ value would round to $2$ _anyway_, so it will contribute no relative error to speak of.